# problem updating 14.04 to latest release

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

Trying to update system ubuntu 14.04 to latest release. keep getting `no new release found` message. Have tried lots of answers from these forums with no luck. Did find out that this system has issues that updating will fix. My system details:

Toshiba satellite C50D - B - 120( x64, originally windows 8.1 pre installed) with 488.4GB hard disk space

AMD E1-6010 APU with AMD Radeon R2 Graphics × 2

graphics - Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)

cant post image so heres the terminal text from what ive tried so far -

```
s@s-SATELLITE-C50D-B:~$ do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
s@s-SATELLITE-C50D-B:~$ /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
bash: /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades: Permission denied
s@s-SATELLITE-C50D-B:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
[sudo] password for s: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
s@s-SATELLITE-C50D-B:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb linux-headers-3.13.0-32 linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

thanks.

Comment: You also need to run `sudo apt-get update` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
do-release-upgrade -d

-d, --devel-release
          Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible
```

If you want to upgrade to the latest release available for an upgrade from your current system then navigate --> System Settings --> Software & Updates --> Updates and change Ubuntu version notification to `any` then go back to terminal and type:

```
do-release-upgrade -c -d
```

You'll get:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '14.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

If you don't have GUI you can just run:

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

and replace `prompt=lts` to `prompt=normal`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend upgrading to the 14.10 version. I think that the 15.04 version (latest release) has still some problems.

To upgrade the 14.10 version, in console:

```
sudo su
[your user password]
gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In this file (**sources.list**), to change all **trusty** words for **utopic** (it is easy by using **Find and Replace** option of **gedit**). After saving the changes, at the same console:

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -f
```

After downloading and installing all packages, you should have your new **Trusty Tahr Ubuntu** system.

**Editing Note:** For upgrading directly to 15.05 version (from 14.04), in the **sources.list** the changes will be all **trusty** words for **vivid**.

Comment: There isn't a direct upgrade path from 14.04 to 15.04.

Comment: I know that. I put: "I recommend upgrading to the 14.10 version. I think that the 15.04 version (latest release) has still some problems". In my case, I will wait 6-8 month for upgrading to 15.05 version.

Comment: @xunilk If you wait 6-8 months, the support period of 15.04 (9 month) will be over.

Comment: Still some bugs in 15.04 version (latest release). Need to wait for next version release.

Comment: I upgraded succesfully to 15.04 with this method.